# How can I prevent leaves from blocking my gutter guard?

Tags: cleaning, home, water

It's been raining heavily here. The tree that is behind my house has grown so that about 5% of its top is over the roof. So there are loads of fallen leaves on my roof.

The problem arises when the water slides through the grid on my gutter, to the downspout. It brings the leaves with it, which accumulate over the grid, and after some time the grid is completely blocked, and won't allow any water to pass through it. I have to manually clean them out to allow water to flow.

Cutting down the tree isn't a good option right now, as I am on a rather busy schedule. I could manage that but I was wondering if there could be any other solution to this.

How can I prevent the leaves from accumulating on the gutter guard?

Comment: Could you clarify what a gutter guard is?

Comment: @MrPhooky [This'll](http://www.google.com/search?q=gutter+guard&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS584US584&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5QUHVaqZG5GxsASu-oDYBQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1920&bih=955) give you a general idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: gutter guard animation]

This looks awesome, but I don't know how easy it would be to DIY. Maybe just a few long pieces of wood? Just an idea.

Consumer Reports recommended DIY ones, such as 'CR Best Buy Amerimax 85198 or 854054,' which they say costs less than $100 and is available at Home Depot for $2.50 for a 20' roll.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks S.E.! If you need assistance on how/what to ask/answer please visit [The Help Center](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help). I think this looks like an excellent idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can't! But you can try adding some larger grids around the drop outlet which will keep it from clogging up a little longer. This grids can be bought, or made as DIY lifehacks from  large bottles with holes or wire mesh bent into shape.

In the long run you do need to keep cleaning the gutter, or trim the tree's overhanging branches.

Answer (score 0):

My gutter guards are half-tubes of plastic-coated wire mesh. C-shaped if you like. They are placed in the gutter with the curve upward, filling the space between gutter and roof edge.

So the leaves don't get caught, they blow or get washed right over the edge. These work really well. I have not needed to clean the gutters since I got them.